# WCF Service - How to specify maximum (and/or minimum) length for string element?

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, wsdl, data-annotations

I am looking for a way to have the maximum (and/or minimum) length for a string element specified in the WSDL generated from a WCF service.

I have looked at [WCF Data Annotations](http://wcfdataannotations.codeplex.com/), which is really neat for implementing the validation, but it doesn't put the constraints into the WSDL, so a client will not be aware of them.

Is there a relatively easy way to have the StringLength Data Annotation attribute reflected in the WSDL? Or, failing that, another way to specify the constraint in a manner that generating the WSDL from the WCF service will have it included?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this please question? having the same problem.

Comment: @Tchaps Sorry for the very delayed response. Unfortunately, I did not. I would have answered this question myself if I had. I take it you had no luck either?